# Magento 1 site indexed by google

Tags: magento-1, indexing, google

Can any one tell me how to magento 1 website indexable by google.
Any help?

Comment: please check - https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-1-x-Technical-Issues/Site-not-getting-indexed-by-Google/m-p/79933#M7149

Comment: @AnasMansuri I dont find solution there. i dont know how can i make by site indexable.

Comment: @AnasMansuri Any idea? Can u help?